# timer resume issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, stopwatch

I have one existing code of stopwatch. and it is working fine but it has functionality that when I click on pause button it changes start button value with Resume and make timer pause. and when I click the start button which has value Resume stopwatch resume and start timer where it pauses.

I have created my code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjahav/sdcqLbe0/17/) here

and I want my start button value as it is and I have to make another resume button with which I have to make resume functionality.

I have made second resume functionality and don't know how can I do this.

actually, I want to start my stopwatch directly from a particular time.

that's why I want code through which I can start my timer from particular time.

can anybody help me in this.

```
<input type="button" value="Start" id="sw_start" />
<input type="button" value="Resume" id="resume" /> // this button made by me
<input type="button" value="Pause" id="sw_pause" />
<input type="button" value="Stop"  id="sw_stop" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="sw_reset" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xeqskro/

I've edited the JSFiddle and added a simple function called `startFromTime` which takes a parameter of milliseconds and adjusts a couple of settings in the APP plugin to start from a specified time. How's that?

The code I added is as follows:

```
function startFromTime(ms) {
    // manually set time difference to desired input
    $.APP.td = parseInt(ms);

    // set state to 'pause' to mimick 'resume' behaviour
    $.APP.state = 'pause';

    // start the timer
    $.APP.startTimer('sw');
}

// call startFromTime() using manual number input
$('#start_custom').on('click', function() {
    var ms = $('#start_time').val();
    startFromTime(ms);
});
```